# Replacing text in label through expression in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, labeling, python-parser

I am using ArcMap.

In the labels I want to alter the text that is displayed, I do not want to change the data in the attribute table.

In the label expression I add the following after checking the advanced checkbox:

```
def FindLabel ([sur_notes]):
  return [sur_notes].replace('a string', 'another string')‍‍
```

The idea is to replace part of a string in the label from the sur_notes text field, however the above throws a syntax error.

I have checked the parser, it is set to python.
The string is stored as text.

Comment: Did you check the *Advanced* checkbox?

Comment: yes, this is in the advanced area

Comment: I suspect you have null data in your sur_notes field. So replace won't work. You need to put a check for null in your code and deal with that.

Answer (score 2):

When I copied your expression to ArcMap, I got the same error message, which in this case seemed to be caused by two invisible trailing characters after the closing `)`.

I solved it by placing the cursor there, and pressing backspace until `)` was gone. Then I added `)` again.

For those who are interested, the characters appeared to be [Zero-width joiners](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-width_joiner). Pasting the snippet from the question in Notepad++, and then opening the file in a hex editor will reveal: `E2 80 8D` (which is the character's code point, U+200D) twice.

Comment: Thanks, I have typed out the whole text to avoid such an issue, I still get the error stating `Error 0 on line 0` saying `Attribute Error: NoneType object has no attribute replace` Therefore the issue seems to be the parser not recognising the replace() function.

Comment: @SpatialDigger I tried that too, and it worked. Other than the trailing characters, your code should work just fine.